# jquery multiselect dropdown check box which gets data from database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a requirement where in I need to display a dropdown check box as follows.

The data has to be pulled from datbase on type ahead.

Is there any jquery plugin to accomplish this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you took a look at [Twitter typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/) ?

Comment: What if you bind your control, and provide filter (Typeahead) from already available options? I think multiselect plugin provides this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could use select2 select-replacement. http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

you can give an ajax property as an data aquire function which can load data from an remote resource. 
http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#ajax